# SQL Database fills field with 0 instead of null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that roughly looks like this:

| Column Name | Data Type | Default/Expression |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | INT |  |
| Year | YEAR | Null |
| Volume | FLOAT | Null |
| x | INT | Null |

I usually upload new data from a csv file (Table Data Import Wizard) and sometime some of these cells are missing, however, instead of inserting NULL to this missing field, MySQL workbench places 0 there.

Currently, it looks like this when I upload new data:

| id | Year | Volume | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 20.5 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 23.5 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018 | 0 | 4 |
| 4 | 2019 | 20 | 0 |

What I want instead is:

| id | Year | Volume | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 20.5 | 1 |
| 2 | Null | 23.5 | Null |
| 3 | 2018 | Null | 4 |
| 4 | 2019 | 20 | Null |

I can run a coalesce to convert these 0s to Null, but is there a setting in MySQL workbench that allows you to automatically set a field to 0 if that cell is missing in the CSV?

I tried to set the Default/Expression to NULL, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: csv is a text file and empty spaces are not null, they are actually equivalent of "' or a zero length string.  Because your field is int (or looks like it's int) mysql is adding 0.  Try coalesce like Senor Linoff suggests

Answer (score 2):

First, the question is why there are `0`s in columns that accept `NULL`s.  Presumably, you are inserting the `0` value.

Second, `COALESCE()` will not help you.  You want `NULLIF()`.  In an update, this would look like:

```
update t
    set year = nullif(year, 0),
        volume = nullif(volume, 0),
        x = nullif(x, 0)
    where 0 in (year, volume, x);
```

However, you should probably fix the process that inserts data so you are inserting the values that you want.